# R - Match values from 2 dataframes based on multiple condtions (when the order of lookup IDs are random)

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

Hi I have two data frames:

```
df1 = data.frame(PersonId1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1),PersonId2=c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,11),
             Played_together = c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1),
             Event=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
             Utility=c(20,-2,-5,10,30,2,1,.5,50,-1,60))


df2 = data.frame(PersonId1=c(11,15,9,1),PersonId2=c(1,5,19,11),
             Played_together = c(1,1,1,1),
             Event=c(1,2,2,2))
```

Where df1 looks like this:

```
      PersonId1 PersonId2 Played_together Event Utility
1          1        11               1     1    20.0
2          2        12               0     1    -2.0
3          3        13               0     1    -5.0
4          4        14               1     1    10.0
5          5        15               1     2    30.0
6          6        16               0     2     2.0
7          7        17               0     2     1.0
8          8        18               0     2     0.5
9          9        19               1     2    50.0
10        10        20               0     2    -1.0
11         1        11               1     2    60.0
```

and df2 looks like this:

```
  PersonId1 PersonId2 Played_together Event
1        11         1               1     1
2        15         5               1     2
3         9        19               1     2
4         1        11               1     2
```

Note that df2 is not simply **df1$played_together==1**. (for eg PlayerId1 = 4 and PlayerId2=14 is not present in df2.

Also note that although df2 is a subset of df1, the order in which individuals appear in df2 is random. For example in **df1** in row 1, we see playerid1 =1 and playerId2 = 11 for event 1. But in **df2** in row 1, we see playerid1 =11 and playerId2 = 1 for event 1. These two cases are exactly same and I want to look up the values of **Utility** from **df1** to **df2**. The merge has to take place for each event. The final output should look like this:

```
  PersonId1 PersonId2 Played_together Event Utility
1        11         1               1     1      20
2        15         5               1     2      30
3         9        19               1     2      50
4         1        11               1     2      60
```

I know that a merge function exists in R, but I do not know what to do when the lookup ids can appear as random. Would appreciate it if someone could help me out a little bit. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have for you:

```
    library(dplyr)
    rbind(left_join(df2, df1, 
          by = c("PersonId2" = "PersonId1", "PersonId1" = "PersonId2", 
            "Played_together" = "Played_together", "Event" = "Event")),
          left_join(df2, df1, 
                     by = c("PersonId1" = "PersonId1", "PersonId2" = "PersonId2", 
         "Played_together" = "Played_together", "Event" = "Event"))) %>%
          filter(!is.na(Utility))
```

Basically it seems like your data sometimes has personid flipped. We can bind two joins together and then filter out those rows that have a utility that is `NA`.

Your output looks like this:

```
    PersonId1 PersonId2 Played_together Event Utility
1        11         1               1     1      20
2        15         5               1     2      30
3         9        19               1     2      50
4         1        11               1     2      60
```

Comment: @Adam Warner Thanks a lot for the answer. Works perfectly. Just a newbie quick follow up question - in your code, which portion takes care of the reversed personid?

Comment: @Prometheus kind of just a work around, but the first left_join you can see I specify hey match personid2 to personid1 and then I bind another join where it is not reversed. So if you do not filter out the NAs. You would get a utility value of NA where personid1 was not reversed.

Comment: Gotcha. I missed out the Personid2 = PersonId1 for some reason. This was really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to create a "Team" column using combination of `PersonId1` and `PersonId2` such a way that it makes `min(PersonId) : max(PersonId)` for two teams. Now, join `df1` and `df2` on `Team` and `Event` to get the desired data.

```
library(dplyr)


df2 %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Team = paste0(min(PersonId1,PersonId2), ":",max(PersonId1,PersonId2))) %>%
  inner_join(df1 %>% rowwise() %>% 
               mutate(Team = 
                   paste0(min(PersonId1,PersonId2), ":",max(PersonId1,PersonId2))),
             by = c("Team", "Event")) %>%
  select(PersonId1 = PersonId1.x,  PersonId2 = PersonId2.x,
             Played_together = Played_together.x, Event, Utility) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   PersonId1 PersonId2 Played_together Event Utility
# 1        11         1               1     1      20
# 2        15         5               1     2      30
# 3         9        19               1     2      50
# 4         1        11               1     2      60
```