# R - Match values using multiple identifiers (when the order of lookup IDs are random)

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

My question is a follow up from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088367/r-match-values-from-2-dataframes-based-on-multiple-condtions-when-the-order-o/51088648#51088648). I am opening a new question here - since this is very different from the last one.

Suppose I have the following two datasets:

```
df1 = data.frame(PersonId1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1),PersonId2=c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,11),
         Played_together = c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1),
         Event=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
         Utility=c(20,-2,-5,10,30,2,1,.5,50,-1,60))
```

This looks like:

```
   PersonId1 PersonId2 Played_together Event Utility
1          1        11               1     1    20.0
2          2        12               0     1    -2.0
3          3        13               0     1    -5.0
4          4        14               1     1    10.0
5          5        15               1     2    30.0
6          6        16               0     2     2.0
7          7        17               0     2     1.0
8          8        18               0     2     0.5
9          9        19               1     2    50.0
10        10        20               0     2    -1.0
11         1        11               1     2    60.0
```

.

```
df2 = data.frame(PersonId1=c(11,15,9,1),PersonId2=c(1,5,19,11),
         Played_together = c(1,1,1,1),
         Event=c(1,2,2,2),Utility=c(25,36,51,64))
```

This looks like:

```
PersonId1 PersonId2 Played_together Event Utility
1        11         1               1     1      25
2        15         5               1     2      36
3         9        19               1     2      51
4         1        11               1     2      64
```

I would like to do the following: Look up each pair (**in each event and for played_together == 1**) in **df2** and match it with the observations in **df1**. If its a match, create a new column in df1, called 'Utility from df2'. It not, put 0.

The challenge for me comes from the fact that the order of the persons are not consistent across df1 and df2. For example in df1 row 1, for event== 1 and played_together == 1 we see: personid1 = 1 and personid2 = 11 whereas in df2, in row 1 I have personid1=11 and personid2 =1, for event == 1 and played_together==1. Thus the two are the same. I would like to take the value of utility from df2 and put it in a new column in df1. if there is no match, then put 0.

The final dataframe should look as follows:

```
    PersonId1 PersonId2 Played_together Event Utility Utility_from_df2
1          1        11               1     1    20.0               25
2          2        12               0     1    -2.0                0
3          3        13               0     1    -5.0                0
4          4        14               1     1    10.0                0
5          5        15               1     2    30.0               36
6          6        16               0     2     2.0                0
7          7        17               0     2     1.0                0
8          8        18               0     2     0.5                0
9          9        19               1     2    50.0               51
10        10        20               0     2    -1.0                0
11         1        11               1     2    60.0               64
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `data.table`:

```
df2 = data.frame(PersonId1=c(11,15,9,1),PersonId2=c(1,5,19,11),
                 Played_together = c(1,1,1,1),
                 Event=c(1,2,2,2),
                 Utility=c(25,36,51,64)) # you had missed adding Utility in your ques


library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df3 <- copy(df2)
colnames(df2) <- c("PersonId2", "PersonId1", "Played_together", "Event", "Utility")
setDT(df2)
df2 <- df2[, c("PersonId2", "PersonId1", "Utility", "Event")]
df3 <- df3[, c("PersonId2", "PersonId1", "Utility", "Event")]
df <- left_join(df1, df2, c("PersonId2", "PersonId1", "Event"))
df <- left_join(df, df3, by = c("PersonId2", "PersonId1", "Event"))
setDT(df)
df[, Utility_from_df2 := ifelse(is.na(Utility), Utility.y, ifelse(is.na(Utility.y), Utility, 0))]
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
df[, c("Utility.y", "Utility") := NULL]
setnames(df, "Utility.x", "Utility")
```

Desired Output:

```
     PersonId1 PersonId2 Played_together Event Utility Utility_from_df2
 1:         1        11               1     1    20.0               25
 2:         2        12               0     1    -2.0                0
 3:         3        13               0     1    -5.0                0
 4:         4        14               1     1    10.0                0
 5:         5        15               1     2    30.0               36
 6:         6        16               0     2     2.0                0
 7:         7        17               0     2     1.0                0
 8:         8        18               0     2     0.5                0
 9:         9        19               1     2    50.0               51
10:        10        20               0     2    -1.0                0
11:         1        11               1     2    60.0               64
```